# Scheme: A iterator function return only one value at the time

Tags: list, iterator, scheme

Lets say, i have a function `range` that returned a list of number by step, I have implemented that and it worked fine. Now, I need to write a iterator function on top of that, so if I run the iterator function on the list, it will return the first element of the list overtime.

```
(define next '(1 2 3 4))

(next) => 1
(next) => 2
(next) => 3
(next) => 4
(next) => '()
```

My question is I don't know what type of syntax of scheme can achieve that since every time we call the function `next`, the will should get refreshed. But i need to implement the next function so that if i call next on the list the second time, the list do not get refreshed, so it will get the second item of the list

Is there any specific method I need to know about to achieve this or do i need to modify my `range` function to do that.

My iteration function looks like this:

```
(define (iterator L)
    (let ((start (car L))
          (step (car (cdr L)))
          (end (car (cdr (cdr L))))
          )
        (lambda ()
            (if (> start end)
                '()
                (set! start
                    (+ start step)
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

My next definitiin

```
(define next (iterator '(0 2 7)))
```

Error message i have is: `Error: execute: unbound symbol: "iterator" []`.

Comment: your range implementation is broken, in fact it does not compile...

Comment: I have rolled back your last edit (as Óscar López suggested) because it invalidated the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, there's a bug in your `range` code:

```
(define (range L)
  (let ((start (car L))
        (step (car (cdr L)))
        (end (car (cdr (cdr L)))))
    (if (> start end)
        '() ; fix this line
        (cons start (range (list (+ start step) step end))))))
```

Now, to create an iterator we need to introduce *state* into our procedure, to remember where we're in each step of the iteration. Also notice that there are two separate concepts here: the *iterator* and the procedure to advance it, we can use currying to return the `next` procedure. Here's my proposal:

```
(define (iter lst)
  (let ((pos lst))               ; store current position
    (lambda ()                   ; return the `next` procedure
      (if (null? pos)            ; are we done?
          '()                    ; then exit
          (let ((cur (car pos))) ; current element
            (set! pos (cdr pos)) ; advance & update state
            cur)))))             ; return current
```

Use it like this:

```
(define next (iter (range '(1 1 3))))
(next)
=> 1
(next) 
=> 2
(next)
=> 3
(next)
=> '()
```

Comment: I have wrote my own iteration function based on the logic you have above, but I ran into a syntax error which I cant seem to understand why, can you please take a look at it.

Comment: I'm not getting that error. If I type your code, it compiles, but `(next)` returns nothing at all. Please accept this question and post a new one, because this is a different problem. Also, I'll revert the question to its original form.